# Winsound не повторяет звук

Tags: python, python-3.x

Модуль Winsound не повторяет звук, я читал, что `winsound.SND_LOOP` нужно использовать вместе с `winsound.SND_ASYNC`, но если я использую `winsound.SND_ASYNC`, то код не работает, а с `winsound.SND_FILENAME` работает, но звук не повторяется. Как решить эту проблему?

Так должен повторяться звук, но код просто не работает

```
import winsound
winsound.PlaySound(r"C:\Users\user\Downloads\discordnotification.wav", winsound.SND_ASYNC + winsound.SND_LOOP)
```

А вот здесь код работает, но звук не повторяется

```
import winsound
winsound.PlaySound(r"C:\Users\user\Downloads\discordnotification.wav", winsound.SND_FILENAME + winsound.SND_LOOP)
```

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.

Comment: А все 3 флага указать не пробовали? `winsound.SND_FILENAME + winsound.SND_ASYNC + winsound.SND_LOOP`. `winsound.SND_FILENAME` - потому что указываете имя файла. `winsound.SND_LOOP` - потому что хотите зациклить. И `winsound.SND_ASYNC` - потому что зацикливание без него не работает.

Comment: @GrAnd пробовал, всё равно не работает

Comment: У меня работает. Что с указанием `winsound.SND_FILENAME`, что без. У вас остальная программа-то какая? А то может вы только эти 2 строчки и запускаете, и программа тут же выходит? С флагом `winsound.SND_ASYNC` функция же сразу завершается чтобы самой работать в фоне, а ваша программа пошла дальше. Вы хотя бы в конце задержку какую перед выходом поставьте что-ли... `import time
          time.sleep(5)`.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в `winsound.SND_ASYNC`. Звук начинает возпроизводиться асинхронно, но программа сразу же завершается. Исправляеться очень просто:

```py
import winsound
winsound.PlaySound(r"C:\Users\user\Downloads\discordnotification.wav", winsound.SND_ASYNC + winsound.SND_LOOP)

while True: # Здесь создаеться бесконечный цикл
    pass
```